# Solution to the equation $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} - 5 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had this equation on my exam :

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} - 5 = 0$$

My friends said the the solution could be :
$$|x-1| = -5$$

 So the solution is nothing!

But I say the solution is:
$$x^2-2x+1 = 25  $$
so $$x = 6\ |\ x = -4$$

My Question here is which solution is right, and why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for tips, I am so new here, I will try to make it!

Comment: You are correct. Your friend would also be correct if they wrote $|x-1| = 5 $.

Comment: @moo My friends said that number in |xx| can't be negative number. That's what makes me wired!

Comment: Did you see what I wrote in my comment $=+5$?? Plot it and see.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I didn't. Now thanks's a lot, it means that my solution is correct and theirs are wrong.

Comment: @moo Wow, Can you please read it again.

Comment: what? Editing -5 to +5 changes everything!!!

Comment: @AhmedAlaa  With that change, your friends' solution is correct and yours is incorrect.  However, making that change also invalidates the answers people wrote for your original question.  I suggest that you change the question back to its original state.  If you are still unclear as to why your friends are right, ask a separate question.

Comment: I know, That's my bad mistake writing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} - 5 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-1)^2} - 5 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow |x-1|-5=0 \\ \Rightarrow |x-1|=5 \\ \Rightarrow x-1=5 \text{ or } x-1=-5 \\ \Rightarrow x=6 \text{ or } x=-4$$ So, your solution is correct!!

$$$$

If the equation is $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + 5 =0$ then we have the following:

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + 5 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-1)^2} + 5 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow |x-1|+5=0 \\ \Rightarrow |x-1|=-5$$

So, there is no solution.

In this case the solution of your friend is correct.

Comment: Re-read it please, i wrote the question wrong!!

Comment: How is now the equation? Is it $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} - 5 = 0$ or $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + 5 = 0$ ? @AhmedAlaa

Comment: I added both cases to my answer... @AhmedAlaa

Answer (score 1):

Your friends added an extraneous negative sign. Start with

> $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} - 5 = 0$

We add 5 to both sides, giving

> $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} = 5$

Taking the square root gives us

> $|x - 1| = 5$

Solving this gives

> $x = 6 | x = -4$

as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is definitely correct:
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{x^2 - 2x +1} - 5 = 0    \\
\Rightarrow \; &x^2 -2x+1 = 25 \\
\Rightarrow \; &(x-6)(x+4) = 0  \\
\Rightarrow \; &x = 6 \text{  or  } x=-4
\end{align}

Your friend's approach is also correct, but he (or she) has a typo. After correcting this, you get:
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{x^2 - 2x +1} - 5 = 0    \\
\Rightarrow \; &|x-1| = 5 \; \text{  (not  }-5)\\
\Rightarrow \; &x = 6 \text{  or  } x=-4
\end{align}